# Does Mockery clone __get method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, mocking, mockery

I am using Laravel 9 together with mockery/mockery version 1.6.6

I have some strange behavior when I mock an Eloquent model.

The eloquent Model has a `__get()` method defined as :

```
    public function __get($key)
    {
        return $this->getAttribute($key);
    }
```

In my understanding, the mockery should not be aware of it.

However, the following test fails:

```
$user = Mockery::mock(User::class);
$user->abasdasd
```

with:

> Mockery\Exception\BadMethodCallException : Received
> Mockery_1_App_User::getAttribute(), but no expectations were specified
> /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php:2222
> /var/www/html/tests/Unit/Services/Bill/TextGenerator/RegistrationInvoiceTextTest.php:29

IT seems that "getAttribute" is called on my mock object when I try to access a property. Why is that? Is the `__get()` method actually inherited from the class that should be mocked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not well-documented but it seems, like accessing magic properties proxies calls to the real magic methods [by design](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/magic_methods.html):

> It is strongly recommended that unit tests and mock objects do not directly refer to magic methods. Instead, refer only to the virtual methods and properties these magic methods simulate. [...] Following this piece of advice will ensure we are testing the real API of classes.

Comment: Uh okay. Do you know how I can then define a property on the mocked eloquent object? Using $mockedEloquent->property = 1; will trigger __set() from Eloquent.

Comment: @Adam I personally just  mocked the magic METHODS even though it's discouraged to do so.